# Como forçar minha variável no php?

Tags: php

```
if ($stmtMoreInformations->execute()) {

    $stmtUpdateMoreInformations = $conn->prepare("UPDATE menu SET only_delivery = :delivery, card_on_delivery = :delivery,
                                                 wifi = :wifi, live_music = :music, open_holiday = :holiday, 
                                                 acessible = :acessible
                                                 WHERE menu_id = :menu");

    $stmtUpdateMoreInformations->bindValue(":menu", $menu);
}
```

Tenho esse update e minhas variáveis estão retornando 1 ou 2, quero forçar elas a retornarem *true* ou *false*, posso usar o *cast*? Como poderia utiliza-lo?

```
$menu = $_POST['menu'];
    $delivery = null;
    if (isset($_POST['delivery'])) {
        $delivery = $_POST['delivery'];
    }

    $cards = null;
    if (isset($_POST['cards'])) {
        $cards = $_POST['cards'];
    }
    $wifi = null;
    if (isset($_POST['wifi'])) {
        $wifi = $_POST['wifi'];
    }
    $music = null;
    if (isset($_POST['music'])) {
        $music = $_POST['music'];
    }
    $holiday = null;
    if (isset($_POST['holiday'])) {
        $holiday = $_POST['holiday'];
    }
    $acessible = null;
    if (isset($_POST['acessible'])) {
        $acessible = $_POST['acessible'];
    }







$stmtMoreInformations = $conn->prepare("SELECT only_delivery, card_on_delivery, wifi, live_music, 
                                        open_holiday, acessible FROM public.menu
                                        WHERE menu_id = :menu");

$stmtMoreInformations->bindValue(":menu", $menu);



if ($stmtMoreInformations->execute()) {

    $stmtUpdateMoreInformations = $conn->prepare("UPDATE menu SET only_delivery = :delivery, card_on_delivery = :card,
                                                 wifi = :wifi, live_music = :music, open_holiday = :holiday, 
                                                 acessible = :acessible
                                                 WHERE menu_id = :menu");

    $stmtUpdateMoreInformations->bindValue(':menu', $menu);
    $stmtUpdateMoreInformations->bindValue(':delivery', $delivery);
    $stmtUpdateMoreInformations->bindValue(':card', $cards);
    $stmtUpdateMoreInformations->bindValue(':wifi', $wifi);
    $stmtUpdateMoreInformations->bindValue(':music', $music);
    $stmtUpdateMoreInformations->bindValue(':holiday', $holiday);
    $stmtUpdateMoreInformations->bindValue(':acessible', $acessible);
    $stmtUpdateMoreInformations->execute();

    echo'delivery: '.$delivery;
    echo'card: '.$cards;
    echo'wifi: '.$wifi;
    echo'music: '.$music;
    echo'd: '.$holiday;
}
```

Comment: Se colocar um trecho do html com o radio, pode ser mais fácil de ajustar a resposta para o caso específico (e ajudar as pessoas que podem postar novas respostas ou alternativas).

Comment: Se quiser adaptar para sua pergunta sobre o mesmo assunto (a que vc deletou faz pouco), basta usar `if( isset($_POST['cards'] ) && ($_POST['cards']    =='1') ) { ` etc para usar o branco ou vazio para falso, 1 e para verdadeiro.

Comment: Obrigada @Bacco mas não solucionei meu problema real ainda.

Comment: Se você postar uma pergunta com o código HTML e mais o PHP podemos tentar ajudar. Sugeriria parar de insistir no cast/bool por que esse definitivamente não é o problema. PHP nao tem esse tipo de problema com tipagem. Ao fazer nova pergunta, ponha as 2 partes, explique o que está acontecendo que a gente tenta ajudar.

Comment: Esse problema em questão eu já resolvi, estou fazendo outra comparação agora. Entre o que está vindo do banco e o que está vindo no meu radio input. Mas obrigada.

Comment: Ok, mas a dica serve para qualquer postagem sua. Sempre ponha o trecho do código atualizado, SQL na parte do banco, etc. - E sobre recuperar radios de DB, caso queira usar no option mesmo. `if( $valordodb = 'seu_verdadeiro') $s1=' selected' else $s2=' selected'`, aí você coloca no html `<option value .....  <?=$s1?>>` no final do verdadeiro e $s2 no falso (selected vale para option, checked pra checkbox) mas a lógica é a mesma.

Comment: Ok, muito obrigada pela dica!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Sobre a conversão pra bool:

Tem várias maneiras, o ideal é fazer o cast na hora do uso e não do retorno.

Algumas possibilidades:

```
$boolMenu = ( $menu == 2 ); // só é true quando for 2

$boolMenu = (boolean) ( $menu - 1 );  // alterna entre zero (false) e 1 (true)
```

Aplicando ao seu POST, dá pra fazer mais simples ainda:

```
$cards     = isset($_POST['cards']    ) && ($_POST['cards']    =='2');
$wifi      = isset($_POST['wifi']     ) && ($_POST['wifi']     =='2');
$music     = isset($_POST['music']    ) && ($_POST['music']    =='2');
$holidays  = isset($_POST['holydays'] ) && ($_POST['holydays'] =='2');
$acessible = isset($_POST['acessible']) && ($_POST['acessible']=='2');
```

Estas linhas acima substituem todo o seu código da pergunta. Não precisa mais de inicialização, nem de *cast*, nem nada.

Com 'Yes' ou 'No', é a mesma lógica:

```
$acessible = isset($_POST['acessible']) && ($_POST['acessible']=='Yes');
```

Sempre usando o valor **verdadeiro** no `==`, com cuidado de deixar maiúsculas e minúsculas da mesma forma que foram digitadas, pois `YES` e `Yes` são coisas completamente diferentes para comparação.

Se quiser exagerar, pode ainda acrescentar um `&& is_string( ... )` logo depois do `isset` para sanitizar *arrays*, mas isso normalmente não acontece num formulário normal. Lembrando que as aspas no '2' são pelo fato de GET e POST sempre serem passados como *string*

Comment: Editei minha pergunta, no caso preciso forçar as variáveis a retornarem da maneira certa. E não o menu. Com a variável menu está tudo ok.

Comment: @AnaCarolinaRibeiro por isso é importante já fazer a pergunta completa. De qq forma, atualizei a resposta para o seu caso, também é super simples

Comment: Mas e para eu tornar ela boolean??

Comment: Ainda está dando invalid parameter number!!

Comment: Aí nao tem nada a ver com sua pergunta, é erro em alguma linha que você não postou na pergunta, e está usando com parâmetros errados. Talvez um binding de DB com alguma `:variavel` sobrando ou faltando, ou alguma funçao com coisa a mais ou a menos. A parte de boolean que foi o que você perguntou eu respondi. Se tiver mais alguma dúvida específicamente sobre a parte do boolean, posso tentar atualizar e ajudar. Se for sobre outra parte do código, seria o caso de uma pergunta separada. Pesquise sobre esse erro, já tem até resposta no site.

Comment: Atualizei lá todo meu código. Dá esse erro aqui:     $stmtUpdateMoreInformations->execute()!!!

Comment: É exatamente o que eu disse, você tem um bind só, e várias variáveis. Tem que ter um bindvalue pra cada :variável. Não adianta fazer só do :menu

Comment: Verdade, muito obrigada!

Comment: corrigi mas ainda está com erro! Na verdade estou usando input radio pro sim e não, ele está pegando sempre 1 nos meus echo mesmo quando está no sim e no não.